# Automator Application to Tar File

Tags: macos, terminal, tar, automator

I have tried creating an application in Automator that when double clicked, will tar my To-Do.txt file. The command I'm using is pretty standard:

`tar -cvzf ToDo.tar.gz /Users/myusername/Desktop/To-Do.txt`

The above command works perfectly when entered into a terminal, so I created an application in Automator and put the 'Run Shell Script' action into the workflow with the command above. However, when I double click the application it does nothing at all.

If I run the workflow in automator, it runs successfully so I know there are no errors.

Can anyone tell me why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get it to work by changing the 'Shell:' option to `/bin/sh` instead of `/bin/bash`.

Works really well. I also changed the specified filename to use arguments `$@` and can now Tar any file with it.